# Disable and rebuild an index in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb

I would like to disable (and later rebuild) all indexes for a given table in an HSQLDB. I know this feature from SQL Server, where you can just write

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON MyTable DISABLE;
```

to disable all indexes for a table and then rebuild them with

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON MyTable REBUILD;
```

I am not even sure, if HSQLDB supports disabling and enabling a single index.

Comment: If you are not sure, check the manual, it's all documented there: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_other_object_creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLDB does not have this feature.

You can perform SHUTDOWN COMPACT to recreate all indexes on all tables.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is indeed supported. However you can drop index and then create it again. 
Something like this:

```
DROP INDEX index [IF EXISTS];
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD INDEX MY_INDEX
```

Take a look on this [doc](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#alter_index-section) for more info.