# HSQLDB index inconsistency

Tags: database, jdbc, hsqldb, indexing

I've encountered a strange behaviour of HSQLDB in our java project. Very simple queries returned inconsistent results. I traced the problem to indices of some tables being not up to date. Unfortunately I'm not at all an expert neither in SQL nor dealing with databases from java.

The HSQLDB version is 2.2.8. I tried to update to 2.2.9 but that didn't help.

Our database is very simple. It contains several independent tables. There are no relations between them. Each table is equipped with indices, one of them unique index combining several columns. Here is an example:

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.MYTABLE(
  A BIGINT DEFAULT -9999 NOT NULL,
  B BIGINT DEFAULT -9999 NOT NULL,
  C NUMERIC(12,7) DEFAULT -9999.0000000 NOT NULL,
  D INTEGER DEFAULT -9999 NOT NULL);

CREATE INDEX IDX1 ON PUBLIC.MYTABLE( A );
CREATE INDEX IDX2 ON PUBLIC.MYTABLE( B );
CREATE INDEX IDX3 ON PUBLIC.MYTABLE( C );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MYTABLE_PRIMARY_KEY ON PUBLIC.MYTABLE( A, B );
```

We usually insert rows and query tables from java program and never update existing rows. Insert operation looks something like this:

```
Connection con = ...; // get connection from 
PreparedStatement stmt;

con.setAutoCommit( false );

stmt = this.con.prepareStatement( 
    String.format( 
       "insert into %s values (?,?,?,?)", "MYTABLE"));

stmt.setLong(1, data1);
stmt.setLong(2, data2);
stmt.setDouble(3, data3);
stmt.setInt(4, data4);

stmt.addBatch()
```

and somewhere else we execute the batch

```
stmt.executeBatch();
stmt.clearBatch();
con.commit();
```

The code is executed in loop, after which we close statement and connection with appropriate methods. Also the connection url has "shutdown=true" at the end, so we expected the database to shutdown correctly.

As I mentioned earlier, I noticed the problem when SQL queries such as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE
```

began returning unreasonable results, such as it returned only about half of the expected number of rows. As an experiment I deleted the unique index from the table and all the queries worked correctly. This is why I think that for some reason the index is not properly updated on insert. The clue to look into index came from googling and reading comments on message boards and forums.

As described in [Disable and rebuild an index in HSQLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12569539/1703316) I used

```
SHUTDOWN COMPACT
```

and that healed all tables in our database, all the data is there and all queries return correct results. I suspect that the author of that question had issue similar to mine.

Ok, my data is safe, so I want to understand and correct the source of the problem.

Is index supposed to be updated on insert? Or this is a false assumption and we need to execute SHUTDOWN COMPACT every time we update the database?

Is it possible that a unique index over multiple columns is the source of the problem?

I would appreciate any suggestions or directions.

Answer (score 0):

The indexes are always updated on insert / delete / update. There shouldn't be a need to execute SHUTDOWN COMPACT for this purpose.

It is not clear what caused the inconsistency. If you can reproduce it with dummy data, then submit a test case to the HSQLDB project and it will be investigated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to reproduce the issue on dummy data.

Comment: Attempted to reproduce the issue with dummy data, but failed. Everything works correctly. Also checked several deployed databases and they all are fine. The problem appears only in two databases which I use for testing on my computer. I think there might have been some special condition which broke the indexes, while I was debugging the application.

Comment: I'm still trying to identify the source of the problem. One thing is that there is an issue with terminating the process from NetBeans IDE using Stop button. It is fully described here [Bug 22641](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22641). In brief, using Stop button will not call for shutdown hooks, and my database closing code is exactly there. And I often use that button, so there could have been a lot of times when the database was not appropriately closed.